# Confused about adding assemblies in PowerShell for using .NET Classes

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I would appreciate some clarification. When using a .NET Framework Class in PowerShell we sometimes have to load the Assembly into memory we have to use the Add-Type Cmdlet in PowerShell. So for instance if I wanted to use the System.ServiceProccess.ServiceController Class I would do something like this

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ServiceProcess
```

But here is where I get confused. The documentation says there are 2 assemblies for the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController Class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=netframework-4.8 namely: **System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll,** and **System.ServiceProcess.dll**

It seems to work no matter which one I add but I would like to know what is happening under the hood of the bonnet.

Even more confusing is the Process class : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8

Here we have 3 assemblies : **System.Diagnostics.Process.dll,  System.dll** and **netstandard.dll**

I can only load System.Dll. The other 2 it simply says the assembly can't be found.

So the question is, if I want to use and .NET Framework Class I Assume I should have all the aasemblies so how do I load them all in PowerShell?

Hope this is clear and thanks for an answer.

Kind regards,

John

Answer (score 0):

`System.ServiceProcess.dll` is in the GAC, and part of the .NET Framework.
`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll` is part of the Core CLR.

But wait a minute - PowerShell is based on the .NET Framework CLR.

If you build your assembly against the correct [netstandard profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), and its dependencies are resolvable, it should be able to run on the .NET Framework.

You can see that `System.ServiceProcess.dll` references `kernel32`, while
`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll` references `api-ms-win-service-core`.

It's sort of the same, but the Core CLR version will have presumably *less* functionality.

As for the others, most of the `System` namespace resides in `mscorlib` and `System.dll`. In recent years, there has been an effort to [make the core library leaner](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/404302/802116) by moving parts of it out, to have out-of-band delivery.

For example, `System.Diagnostics.Process.dll` now ships as a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Process/), which enables faster rollouts to users rather than shipping a major .NET Framework update that targets are required to install.

If you're using regular Powershell and not [Powershell Core](https://aka.ms/pscore6), you can just reference .NET Framework assemblies and not see confusing

Answer (score 0):

MSDN fails to properly indicate which type belongs to which assembly either in .NET Framework, .NET Core or .NET Standard.

You can use [.NET API Catalog](https://apisof.net/) instead:

- [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://apisof.net/catalog/92ca053e-c68f-f9fa-c50b-ff7a178b94ed)
- [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://apisof.net/catalog/04e6b2f8-f1d6-04fe-13d5-8e6d09909d50)